# Add uiimage in nsdocumentdirectory and retrieve

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, uiimage

I am saving images to nsdocumentdirectory like this

```
NSArray *pathArr = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                       NSUserDomainMask,
                                                       YES);
NSString *path = [[pathArr objectAtIndex:0]

                  stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"img.data" ];

NSLog(@"path=%@",path);


NSData *retrievedData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];

imgView.image=[UIImage imageWithData:retrievedData];
```

The problem is only one image is saved. If I try to display an image the last saved image is displayed. How to solve this?

Comment: Try to save images into a plist. Using index you can have the access to all images you saved.

Comment: From where do you get these images? It will save only one image because they are being overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

Use different image name for every image, then you'll get all the images...

Comment: @baijukrishnan use unique image names and change the code as per

Answer (score 1):

Save each image by appending an integer at end. LIKE:

```
NSString *path = [[pathArr objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"img%d.data",integerCount]];
```

Also:

```
integerCount++;
```

Tell me if it helps! Will give u an alternative sol.

Comment: That won't be a feasible solution what happens when integerCount is set to zero again when app restarted? He may have to use `NSuserDefault` in this case.